# Как согласовать архивацию и отношения один к одному?

Tags: laravel, one-to-many, laravel-9

У меня есть две таблицы в БД - пользователи и их резюме. Изначально у одного пользователя должно быть одно резюме. Но при этом как сюда вписать идею архивации? Т.е. при критичных изменениях резюме нельзя изменять, можно только заархивировать. Но как-то сюда не вписывается один к одному.

Была идея добавить статус резюме(заархивировано или в использовании) и дату архивации.
Просто я уже реализовал часть функционала, и в нём подразумевалась один к одному, т.е использовалось Auth::User()->resume.

Стоит ли менять на один ко многим или из этой ситуации можно как-то выйти?

Comment: Не понятно что именно вы подразумеваете под архивацией? Дублировать заявление? Типо обычного и архивированного? и для этого делать один ко многим? тогда нет смысла переделывать. Зачем дублировать, когда решение статусом или датой решает проблему.  Если в будущем захотите чтобы пользователь мог добавлять несколько заявлений, то всё равно придется переделывать. Поэтому лучше сделать сейчас это. Решение это переделать связи + добавить статус и дату для функционала архивации, то  есть и то и то.

Comment: Можно менять запрос в модели, один к одному. и там взять тот который не заархивирован. если добавить новую колонку. И еще добавить другую привязку в модели и взять архивы, где тебе нужно будет.